# How to set a webpage content to 100% on any screen resolution?

Tags: html, css, web

I am designing my first webpage. I have completed almost all the work but now the problem lies in screen resolution. I start designing on 1920x1080p of screen resolution but when i check it on 1080x768p screen the content was missing and overlapped. Now i set the screen size of my Laptop to 1080x768 and set the webpage but while I turned it back to 1920x1080 on the right side content was missing mean only in the 1080x768p screen while i have used following code.

`body {width:100%; hight:100%;}`

It just fills the background images to full screen while content does not displays on full screen what to do any help?

Comment: Please post your HTML code and CSS

Comment: Very hard to help without seeing the code from your webpage. Please try and recreate the issue on jsfiddle.net and suppky the link to your fiddle when done. The body of a web page is 100% by default btw. You also have a typo above hight should be height.

Comment: Did you try `html, body {height:100%; width:100%; margin:0px; padding:0px;}`

Comment: It is `height: 100%`, not `hight: 100%`.

Comment: I am very thankful to you for such a quick response but I am beginner and unfortunately i don't know about jsfiddle.net but I can give you my code of CSS and HTML files if it is necessary. Actually I was experiencing to create a webpage by editing a template and check how it works.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add to html and the body

```
html,body{
    height:100%;
}
/**reset padding of body**/
body{padding:0;}
```

(the width of 100% is auto)

[LIVE EXAMPLE](http://codepen.io/elad2412/pen/tvsKI)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I Have tried this code but it does not works for me tell me how can i show you the code of CSS and HTML files of my template?

Comment: you can use codepen.io, to show me the issue(you need a user for that), or give me an URL of the issue.

Comment: you need to give height 100% all the way until the container, that need to be 100% height.